# How to run Javascript in Wordpress Admin control panel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm creating a WordPress plugin that returns the value of a select box when an admin selects a value from the select box in admin panel, however, it doesn't seem to work. The alert window doesn't pop up. Here's my HTML code.

```
<select id="sweets">
  <option>Chocolate</option>
  <option>Candy</option>
  <option>Taffy</option>
</select>
<div id="choice"></div>
```

Here's my code for the plugin.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
function theme_name_scripts(){
    wp_register_script('selection', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/selections.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script('selection');
}
?>
```

And lastly, here's my Javascript code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#sweets").change(function() {
        var str = "";
        jQuery("select option:selected").each(function() {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
        });
        jQuery( "#choice" ).text( str );
    }).change();
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i go it to work. I have to use plugin_dir_url instead of get_stylesheet_directory_uri(), plugin_dir_url(__FILE__ ).'js/selections.js'.

Answer (score 1):

`admin_enqueue_scripts` hook  is the first action hooked into the wp admin scripts actions.

so you should use this

```
<?php add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' ); ?>
```

instead of

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```